# How to do this in pure CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar DIV floating on the right side of my page. The sidebar's CSS

```
  #sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 22px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    max-width: 300px;
    overflow:scroll;
  }
```

I am currently preventing the content in the main body on my page from overlapping with the sidebar using a javascript function

```
function handleResize() {
    var sbw = document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetWidth;
    var ww = document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var bodyWidthVal = 1000;
    $("body").css('width', Math.min(bodyWidthVal,(-9 + ww - sbw)));
}
```

Which is called on detection of window resized or zoomed (the latter caputured via the mousewheel event). The magic number '-9' is somehow also necessary, as it appears that in the web browser I am using (IE 11) and sidebar.offsetWidth is not capturing the width of the border around the sidebar

This is working, but I'd rather get rid of this klugy solution if it can be accomplished in pure CSS.

Comment: Just float your sidebar to the right and your done. Working with static units will only look good on particular viewports. Also, in CSS the `width` and `height` properties only relate to the size of the content area. Padding, borders and margins are separate sizes above and beyond that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't understand your advice. I thought I was floating my sidebar on the right

Comment: No, you were manually positioning it to the right with fixed static values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much simpler solution (actually there are several) that doesn't require JavaScript at all.

Just float your content and sidebar and your done.

Working with static units will only look good on particular viewports. Also, in CSS the width and height properties only relate to the size of the content area. Padding, borders and margins are separate sizes above and beyond that. This default behavior can be overridden in CSS by setting `box-sizing:border-box` on any element(s) that you want sized according to their content, padding and borders (margins will still not be included).

See comments in the code:

```css
/* Change box model default sizing so that padding and borders are
   counted into the width of an element */
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

#wrapper {
  width:100vw; /* as wide as the viewport */
}

#mainContentArea {
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:#e0e0e0;
  width:80%;
  float:left; /* align element to left of row allowing next element to float up */
  height:100vh;
}

#sidebar {
  border:1px solid red;
  background-color:#808080;
  width:20%;
  float:left;  /* float to left until another floated element is found */
  height:100vh;
  min-width:100px; /* Don't let the sidebar get smaller than 100px */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="mainContentArea">
  
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply calculations in your CSS so the divs don't overlap. Ex:

```
<div class="right-sidebar"></div>
<div class="main-body"></div>
```

in CSS:

```
.right-sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
}
.main-body{
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
  height: 1000px;
}
```

If your sidebar width is dynamically changing then you can get the width in JS and alter the main-body's width property accordingly in JS.